# How to show that these two spaces are homotopy equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

If $X_{1}$ =  $\mathbb{S}^{2} \vee S^{1} $( here $S^{1}$ is attached outside to $\mathbb{S}^{2}$ ) and $X_{2}$ =  $\mathbb{S}^{2}$ with a diameter joining north pole and south pole. In the second case it is becoming wedge but $S^1$ is inside of $\mathbb{S}^{2}$. It is not clear to me how this two space are homotopy equivalent. How to continuously deform one space to another?

Comment: Check out #1 in this http://www.math3ma.com/mathema/2016/4/18/clever-homotopy-equivalences or page 11/12 in Hatcher. I know the arc joining the north and south pole in these diagrams is outside the sphere, but the end effect of both is the same, to identify the north and south poles (by contracting the arc to a point).

Comment: Whether it's inside or outside doesn't matter; you can see this clearly in 4d rather than 3d. You can just rotate from inside to outside using a 4th dimension. It's a little easier to picture the analogue one dimension down. I guess you can also use a sphere eversion but this is heavy-duty.

Comment: $S^2$ with $S^1$ inside is *homeomorphic* to $S^2$ with $S^1$ outside. Take $S^1$ point by point from one to the other: you can do this directly.

Answer (score 0):

A figure for this situation is

[image: sphere]

which is Fig 7.9 taken from the pdf of [Topology and Groupoids](http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html).

Contracting to a point the outside line on the right gives the left hand figure. On the other hand just moving the the top dot of the right hand figure over the sphere to coincide with the bottom dot, gives $S^2 \vee S^1$. (I may have said this somewhere else on this site!)